# can you have too many dto/bo - mapping method

Tags: design, .net, project, projects-and-solutions

I have a windows service, 2 web services and a web interface that need to follow the same path (data wise).

So I came up with two ways of creating my solution.

[image: first one]

My concern is the fact that the UI/WS/etc will have their own kind of DTO (let's say the model in ASP.Net MVC) that should be mapped to a DTO so the SL can then map it to a BO then mapping it to the proper EF6 DTO so that I can save it in a database.

So I'm thinking of doing it this way

[image: second one]

to remove one level of mapping.

Which one should I take? Or is there a 3rd solution?

Comment: I tried both, and the latter one is my current solution. I think my life is better with that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an implementation of an enterprise service bus. We have a customer-facing web service API, a web service that drives the web-based user interface, at least a dozen different windows services that run on client machines, a half-dozen services that run on servers, along with three different databases (Couchbase, Elasticsearch, SQL).

I made the decision up front to create a "core" library which is essentially nothing but simple objects and utility code. This contains the objects and messages that get passed around the application. I then have another set of similar libraries for the client-side and server-side services.  Finally, I have my web service libraries, where either they pass simple objects from the core, or I have created endpoint-specific input/output classes for each web method, which are promptly converted into "core" classes so they can be moved around the application.

The advantage to this is that I have a write-once, use anywhere architecture which is extremely efficient. It is easy to promote and demote classes into the core when necessary. The drawback is that if you have multiple solutions in Visual Studio, any sort of refactoring really requires all projects in existence to be open so you can accomplish the renaming without introducing compiler errors.  In the end, if I had to do this over again, I would do the same thing. It really has been a good structure for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with proper domain model, which can be used across SL,BL and DAL. And for WebServices / WindowsService and for UI i would use appropriate DTO, which could be different but that makes sense because each service might expose different functionality. For example imagine the domain is like,

```
Order 
{
    long orderId { get; set;}
    decimal value { get; set;}
    Customer customer { get; set;}
    List<Orderline> orderlines { get }

    void Add(Product p,qty q)
    {
        orderlines.Add(new Orderline(){order = this, product = p,qty = q,unitPrice = p.unitPrice});
        value += p.unitPrice * q;
    }
}

Customer
{
    long customerId { get; set;}
    string firstName { get; set;}
    string lastName { get; set;}
}

OrderLine
{
    Order order { get; set; }
    Product product { get; set;}
    decimal qty { get; set;}
    decimal unitPrice { get; set;}
}

Product
{
   long productId { get; set;}
   string productName { get; set;}
   decimal unitPrice { get; set;}
}
```

And this domain model can be persisted / contains business logic also. So this model can be used across SL/BLL/DAL.

In the web service when you want to get order details, you might want to map into a DTO like,

```
OrderWSDTO
{
     long orderId { get; set;}
     string customerName { get; set; }
}

OrderLineWSDTO
{
    string productName { get; set;}
    decimal quantity { get; set;}
    decimal value { get; set;}
}
```

However in UI (order list) it could be totally different representation.

```
OrderSummaryUIDTO
{
    string orderId { get; set;}
    decimal value { get; set;}
    string commaSeparatedProductNames { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My instinct here is that the Service Layer doesn't need to know about DTOs, so based on that I'd say your second architecture makes more sense. Some of your presentation layer might need to map into specialised objects such as the DTOs and view models, but it may also be appropriate to use naked BOs for others if the data are already in a usable form.